# How can I make a conversation with a chatbot expire?

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I've noticed that sometimes the users are interacting with the bot, and sometimes they leave after the bot asked for some information. So the next time the user interacts with the bot the bot will still be expecting the input for the question.

I want the conversation to expire after, let's say 60 minutes, after that time even if the bot was expecting the input to a question the user can start a new conversation without having to worry with providing an valid answear to a question that was made one or two days ago.

Is there a way to achieve this? If so, how?

Comment: are you using the node.js or the C# SDK?

Comment: Hi @PavelVeller. I'm using C#.

Comment: You can try setting alarm using [Dialogs](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dialogs.html#alarmBot) after 60 mins of user.typing = false and call DeleteProfileScorable as suggested by Ezequiel Jadib.

Answer (score 2):

You could mimic what the [DeleteProfileScorable](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/DeleteProfileScorable.cs) does:

```
this.stack.Reset();
botData.UserData.Clear();
botData.PrivateConversationData.Clear();
await botData.FlushAsync(token);
```

where stack is the `IDialogStack` and botdata is the `IBotData`

If you are planning to do that from the controller, I think you will have to use `Autofac` to resolve both dependencies.